# Querystring support in ion-router (with StencilJs)

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs, ionic5

I have a StencilJS app with Ionic web components using the following routing setup:

```html
<ion-router useHash={false}>
  <ion-route url="/home" component="page-home"/>
  <ion-route url="/login" component="page-login"/>
  <ion-route url="/main" component="page-main">
</ion-router>
```

When I receive a 401 error from the api, I would like to redirect to the login page, with the current url as a redirect querystring parameter (in order to redirect the user back to where he came from), like so:

```js
const navCtrl: HTMLIonRouterElement = document.querySelector("ion-router");
fetch('https://someapi.com/users/1').then(
  res => navCtrl.push('/main'),
  err => navCtrl.push(`/login?redirect=${window.location.pathname}`)
);
```

When I do this an I receive an error from the api, and I want to navigate to the login page with the current route as querystring parameter, Stencil throws the following error: `[ion-router] the path does not match any route`.

How can I use the querystring with the ion-router?

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in 5.1.0, see my [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19707)

Comment: It has indeed been fixed in 5.1.1, so the workaround is not needed anymore. Thanx for the update, @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's currently a bug in Ionic (see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19707).

To work around it for the moment, you could probably use

```js
navCtrl.push('/login');
history.replaceState(undefined, '', `?redirect=${window.location.pathname}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction! The code you provided did not change the url, because `navCtr.push` returns a promise. You have to wait for it to finish before you can change the state. I ended up with this working workaround:

```js
const navCtrl: HTMLIonRouterElement = document.querySelector("ion-router");
fetch('https://someapi.com/users/1').then(
  res => navCtrl.push('/main'),
  err => {
     navCtrl
        .push(`/login`)
        .then(() => history.replaceState(undefined, '', `?redirect=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)}`))
  }
);
```

It's strange that such widely used frameworks like Ionic and Stencil don't support common querystrings. I hope they will fix this issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

i build a native function to get every parameter from the querystring,

```
export const RouterGetUriParam = (name) => {
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  if (urlParams.has(name)) {
    return urlParams.get(name);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

you can use it in stencil like this:

```
 @Prop() withMore: boolean = (RouterGetUriParam("withMore") == 'true')
```

the urlparam looks like `?withMore=true`